# Custom Profile Field for <textarea>

Tags: profiles

Thanks to this [tutorial](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/09/10/adding-and-using-custom-user-profile-fields), I learned and was able to create a custom profile that use input text for profile links.

here are the codes used from the tutorial:

```
/* add custom profile field */
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'my_show_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'my_show_extra_profile_fields' );

function my_show_extra_profile_fields( $user ) { ?>

    <h3>Extra profile information</h3>

    <table class="form-table">

        <tr>
            <th><label for="twitter">Twitter</label></th>

            <td>
                <input type="text" name="twitter" id="twitter" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'twitter', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
                <span class="description">Please enter your Twitter username.</span>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
<?php }

/* save custom profile field */
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'my_save_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'my_save_extra_profile_fields' );

function my_save_extra_profile_fields( $user_id ) {

    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
        return false;
    update_usermeta( $user_id, 'twitter', $_POST['twitter'] );
}

/* display custom profile field */ 
function my_author_box() { ?>
    <div class="author-profile vcard">

        <?php if ( get_the_author_meta( 'twitter' ) ) { ?>
            <p class="twitter clear">
                <a href="http://twitter.com/<?php the_author_meta( 'twitter' ); ?>" title="Follow <?php the_author_meta( 'display_name' ); ?> on Twitter">Follow <?php the_author_meta( 'display_name' ); ?> on Twitter</a>
            </p>
        <?php } // End check for twitter ?>
    </div><?php
}
```

I've try changing this part:

```
<input type="text" name="twitter" id="twitter" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'twitter', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" />
```

to:

```
<textarea type="text" name="twitter" id="twitter" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'twitter', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text"></textarea>
```

So that it'll use a textarea instead of a textbox. Whenever I hit save profile, nothing is saved in the textarea, so anything on it is deleted.

How do I fix this so, it'll save whatever is in the textarea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
<textarea type="text" name="twitter" id="twitter" class="regular-text"><?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'twitter', $user->ID ) ); ?></textarea>
```

Note, the input field has a value attribute while the textarea has it's content between `<textarea>` and `</textarea>`

Comment: thanks, it worked. Do you know if there's a way to disable css and js for whatever is entered in the textarea?